# Taking multiple files (arguments) from Windows shell context menu on C#

Tags: c#, windows

I am writing a C# application and it takes files as argument, I added it to shell context menu with code listed below;

```
if (((CheckBox)sender).CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Classes\\*\\shell\\" + KEY_NAME + "\\command");

                if (key == null)
                {
                    key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\*\\shell\\" + KEY_NAME + "\\command");
                    key.SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath + " \"%1\"");
                }
            }
            else if (((CheckBox)sender).CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Classes\\*\\shell\\" + KEY_NAME);

                if (key != null)
                {
                    Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree("Software\\Classes\\*\\shell\\" + KEY_NAME);
                }
```

It is working good, but if I select multiple files, multiple instances of application running.
for example if I select 5 files 5 application is opening, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Detect if an [instance of your application is already](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) running on startup.

If it does, [send the command line arguments to the running instance](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ipc_wmcopy.aspx) and exit the new instance.