# Windows Explorer right click context menu for files and folders

Tags: c++, windows, shell, contextmenu, windows-explorer

my question is similar into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689225/adding-a-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-right-click-context-menu-in-c-sharp), but that didn't gave all info I need, or I didn't understand that very well.

I want that in file context menu there would be option to notify my app.

I added keys:

```
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Classes/*/shell/MyApp/command::"C:\\path\\test.exe" "%1"
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Classes/Folder/shell/MyApp/command::"C:\\path\\test.exe" "%1"
```

Code of test:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        std::cout << argv[i] << "\r\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but... If I mark a few files/folders and right click and select my added option, many test apps launches.

This is not the behaviour I want, I want that all paths would be passed into single instance of my app as list of `argv`'s, does anyone knows how to do that?

BTW. I'm coding with `C++` but I think it isn't matter as it is business with Windows shell.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use DDE I believe. But that's not recommended. Better would be a shell extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the right way is to write [ContextMenuHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881.aspx) and register it as shell extension.

You can find lot of samples like [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/ATLShellExtContextMenuHandl-e5c5fc23), [here](http://yanaware.com/com4me/ShellExtGuide1.php-author=Michael%20DUNN&mail=mdunn@inreach.com&url=http---home.inreach.com-mdunn&idTute=2.htm) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2012/05/15/sample-of-may-15th-c-windows-shell-context-menu-handler.aspx)

Context menu handlers are registered under key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

There are similar questions on SO already:

[How to pass in multiple file/folder paths via a right-click event (verb) to an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826791/how-to-pass-in-multiple-file-folder-paths-via-a-rigth-click-eventverb-to-an-ex)

[How to Pass MULTIPLE filenames to a Context Menu Shell Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440715/how-to-pass-multiple-filenames-to-a-context-menu-shell-command)

[Windows context menu for multiple files [C++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972800/windows-context-menu-for-multiple-files-c)

[Taking multiple files (arguments) from Windows shell context menu on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878145/taking-multiple-files-arguments-from-windows-shell-context-menu-on-c-sharp)

Comment: None of the answers you have linked actually provide a solution.