# How to add custom context menu to system right click menu

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, contextmenu, system

I have developed Windows form application, that will protect word, excel and PDF file with password.

My application is providing UI for browsing files to select for encryption.

Now i need to add more functionality like, when user right click on any Word, Excel or PDF file in windows explorer then in right click menu i need to add my item, which will select that file and invoke my application with it and that file is shown selected in my application.

in short, i need to add menu entry in system right click menu having my application icon, for example same as winrar and winzip software provide their item in system right click menu.

I have searched it over Google and nothing found help full, just found solution to add registry entry to **shell** but nothing found regarding adding icon along with it, how to get selected file's path to open it with my application from right click. and how to add it with setup project to register at the time of installation and un-register at the time of un-installtion.

I have developed my application with the help of VS2010 and C# 3.5.

Comment: [Icon](http://superuser.com/questions/392225/how-can-i-add-an-icon-to-my-custom-context-menu-item-in-windows-7) and [How to pass in multiple file/folder paths via a rigth-click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740846/windows-explorer-right-click-context-menu-for-files-and-folders)

Answer (score 0):

Context menu in C# is tricky. Here is simple way to add item to context menu using registry: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15171/Simple-shell-context-menu
There are some limitation with this approach.

If you need something more complex it'll be easier to use this library: http://www.contextmenu.net/

I hope this helps.